# Bound observable collection update without 'RemoveOf' & 'Insert'

Tags: c#, mvvm, textbox, observablecollection

Currently I am trying to implement an observable collection which is bound to a data template (WPF-MVVM). During initialization it loads the default value to observable collection. Idea is:

1. User provides some value on the textbox,
2. presses ENTER key
3. increments a counter and updates the count value on textblock which is located near the text box.

The purpose is to track how times the text value has been changed by the user.

Right now it is working with 'IndexOf', 'RemoveAt' and 'Insert'. Is there a way to do without 'RemoveAt' and 'Insert'.

I feel something wrong on my code? Can anybody help it.

**InputDataTemplate.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Name}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Count}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="IpDataTb" Grid.Column="1" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding }" MethodName="IpDataTrig" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**TestView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InputDataTemplate" >
        <local:InputDataTemplate DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF0254B4" BorderThickness="1" >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputDatas}"
                          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource InputDataTemplate}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**DataService.cs:**

```
using MyObsrCollTest.ViewModels;

namespace MyObsrCollTest.Services
{
    public class InputDataService : BindableBase
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set;  }

        public void IpDataTrig(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var IpDataTb = new TextBox();
            IpDataTb = (TextBox)sender;

            if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) &&(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpDataTb.Text)))
            {
                this.Data = IpDataTb.Text;
                ObsrCollTestVm.TestMe(this.Name, this.Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ObsrCollTestVm.cs:**

```
private ObservableCollection<InputDataService> _InputDatas;
static int _count = 0;

public ObsrCollTestVm(void)
{  

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {

        var l_InputDatas = new InputDataService();
        l_InputDatas.Name = i.ToString();
        l_InputDatas.Count = "0";
        l_InputDatas.Data = "?";
        _InputDatas.Add(l_InputDatas);
    }
}
```

**Basic initialization routine:**

```
public ObservableCollection<InputDataService> InputDatas
{
    get 
    {
        if (_InputDatas == null)
        {
            _InputDatas = new ObservableCollection<InputDataService>();
        }

        return _InputDatas; 
    }
}
```

**New Observable collection:**

```
public static void TestMe(string name, string data)
{

    var found = _InputDatas.FirstOrDefault(element = > element.Name == name);
    if (found != null)
    {
        int i = _InputDatas.IndexOf(found);
        found.Count = _count++;
        _InputDatas.RemoveAt(i);
        _InputDatas.Insert(i, found);
    }
}
```

**Increment the count value:**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it can be summarized as:

> "I would like to be able to change the `Count` property of my `InputDataService` class objects and have that change reflected in that item's `Label`, without having to modify the `ObservableCollection<InputDataService>` itself."

Is that correct?

If so, then the solution is for your `InputDataService` class to correctly provide notifications of property changes. Normally, this would mean either inheriting `DependencyObject` and implementing your properties as dependency properties, or just implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

But in your example, you seem to be inheriting a class named `BindableBase` already. If that class is in fact the `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase` class, then it already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all you need to do is take advantage of that.

For example:

```
public class InputDataService : BindableBase
{
    private int _count;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value); }
    }
    public string Data { get; set;  }

    public void IpDataTrig(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var IpDataTb = new TextBox();
        IpDataTb = (TextBox)sender;

        if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) &&(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpDataTb.Text)))
        {
            this.Data = IpDataTb.Text;
            ObsrCollTestVm.TestMe(this.Name, this.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- In the above, I only fixed the issue for the `Count` property. You can apply similar changes to the other properties to get them to update correctly.
- In your `TestMe()` method, you seem to be using the `Count` property as an `int`, but it was declared in your code example as a `string`. Lacking a better way to reconcile that discrepancy in your code example, I've just changed the property declaration in the example above to use `int` instead of `string`.
- This example assumes you are using .NET 4.5, in which the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute is supported. If you're using an earlier version of .NET, then you will need to add the property name to the `SetProperty()` call. E.g.:
   `SetProperty(ref _count, value, "Count");`

With these changes, you should be able to write `TestMe()` like this:

```
public static void TestMe(string name, string data)
{
    var found = _InputDatas.FirstOrDefault(element = > element.Name == name);
    if (found != null)
    {
        found.Count = _count++;
    }
}
```